# Ruby AWS::S3::S3Object (aws-sdk): Is there a method for streaming data as there is with aws-s3?

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

In aws-s3, there is a method (AWS::S3::S3Object.stream) that lets you stream a file on S3 to a  local file.  I have not been able to locate a similar method in aws-sdk.

i.e. in aws-s3, I do:

```
File.open(to_file, "wb") do |file|
  AWS::S3::S3Object.stream(key, region) do |chunk|
    file.write chunk
  end
end
```

The AWS::S3:S3Object.read method does take a block as a parameter, but doesn't seem to do anything with it.

Answer (score 6):

The aws-sdk gem now supports chunked reads of objects in S3.  The following example gives a demonstation:

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new
File.open(to_file, "wb") do |file|
  s3.buckets['bucket-name'].objects['key'].read do |chunk|
    file.write chunk
  end
end
```

Comment: Can I specify the chunk size?

Comment: As far as I know, Ruby Net::HTTP does not allow you to control the size of each yielded chunk.

Comment: Anyone know how to do this with the aws s3 sdk v3? object.read no longer exists

Comment: @rigyt You can use `Aws::S3::Object#get` or `Aws::S3::Client#get_object`. Both support passing a block argument.

Answer (score 2):

**At this time, not officially.** I found this thread in the official AWS Ruby forum:

[Does the ruby aws gem support streaming download from S3](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=295587). Quoting AWS staff:

> Unfortunately there is not a good solution baked into the aws-sdk gem. We are looking into way we could make this much simpler for the end user.

There's sample code for downloading in chunks. You might want to have a look at that for inspiration.

Comment: The aws-sdk gem now supports streaming reads.  The forum topic has been updated to reflect this.